# How to pull out Data Array from CoreData TableView array, put it into a new Array and export it as csv?

Tags: arrays, swift, csv

I have an app that takes user inputs in an `alertController`, and then this values will be stored in `CoreData` which is then displayed in a `tableview`. I concatenated all the strings to gather with a comma as separator to make it easier for me to export a csv. However, when I print out the CoreData entity, I get an array that is quite complicated. The array looks like this:

> [ (entity: AlarmItems; id: 0xc2bccd37cb753acb  ; data: {
>       alarmAttributes = "Example Name, 24/11/2019, 1500, True, NIL";
>   }),  (entity: AlarmItems; id: 0xc2bccd37cb653acb  ; data: {
>       alarmAttributes = "Example , 12/12/2019, 24/11/2019, True, NIL";
>   })]

I would like to pull out just that parts after `alarmAttributes` to be exported into a CSV for further use.

I looked at `NSEntityMapping` but that did not help me. I'm quite stuck right now. I do not know how to approach the problem. Is my approach even correct in the first place? Is it even possible to export a csv using a an array that I create? The idea is to have the csv be stored in the iOS Device which can then be emailed elsewhere.

My ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var alarmItems: [NSManagedObject] = []
    let cellId = "cellId"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "AlarmItems")
        do {
            alarmItems = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Failed to fetch items", err)
        }
    }

    @objc func addAlarmItem(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("this works")
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Item", message: "Please fill in the blanks", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { [unowned self] action in

            //combined string of attributes
            let myStrings: [String] = alertController.textFields!.compactMap { $0.text }
            let myText = myStrings.joined(separator: ", ")

            self.save(myText)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Name of Engineer"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Date of Alarm in DD/MM/YYYY"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Time of Alarm in 24h (eg: 2300)"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Please indicate True/False (type True or False)"
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Insert comments (if any), or NIL"
        }


        alertController.addAction(saveAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func save(_ itemName: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "AlarmItems", in: managedContext)!
        let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
        item.setValue(itemName, forKey: "alarmAttributes")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            alarmItems.append(item)

        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Failed to save an item", err)
        }
    }

    @objc func exportCSV(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        //will work on exporting csv in the future
        return
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return alarmItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        let alarmItem = alarmItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = alarmItem.value(forKeyPath: "alarmAttributes") as? String
        return cell
    }
```

}

Comment: Please refactor your design. A  single string representing a lot of attributes in Core Data is awful. Declare **one attribute for each** of the comma separated values. And CSV is the worst text format for sharing data because it's not standardized. Consider to use JSON or Property List. And for the form use the Eureka library, a pretty powerful form generator

Comment: You have a class AlarmItems generates from your model and that class has a property alarmAttributes that you can read